# How to read folder file using Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hdfs

I have a hdfs folder, in this folder has many files txt.
I want to read content in these files using spark.

My code:

```
// Create spark session
    val spark = SparkSession.builder()
                  .master("spark://master:7077")
                  .appName("Indexing data to elasticsearch")
                  .getOrCreate()

    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

    // Read folder file
    val df:DataFrame = spark.read.text("hdfs://master:9000/user/file/shakespeare")
```

I want to get the content of each file in my folder from DataFrame. How should I do?

Comment: What do you mean at `I want to get the content of each file in my folder from DataFrame`? Does that mean you want the result to be a dataframe with the filenames and file contents as columns?

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the many cases where RDDs seem to be way more flexible than DataFrames, because RDDs provide the **wholeTextFiles** method.

The **wholeTextFiles** method is basically like **textFile** but instead of reading the input per lines in all of the files, **it reads and stores a record/PairRDD/key-value pair per file**. The schema of the result RDD will be like this:

```
(path_to_file, file_contents)
```

(However, one must be quite careful using this method because you probably can't predict the length of the contents of the files under a directory, so this can result into running out of memory).

So let's say we have a number of text files (*a.txt*, *b.txt*, ...), each named by the alphabet letter that they have in their contents like shown below:

Using the **wholeTextFiles** method will result in the following RDD pairs (where you might wanna get rid of the full path of each file as the key of each pair for better readability):

```
(hdfs:/.../.../a.txt,a aa aaa aaaa aaaaa)
(hdfs:/.../.../b.txt,b bb bbb bbbb bbbbb)
(hdfs:/.../.../c.txt,c cc ccc cccc ccccc)
(hdfs:/.../.../d.txt,d dd ddd dddd ddddd)
(hdfs:/.../.../e.txt,e ee eee eeee eeeee)
```

After using this method, all that's left to do based on your question is to convert the result RDD to a DataFrame were each record will have its data in two columns (named by you): *file_name* and *content*.

```
+---------+-------------------+
|file_name|            content|
+---------+-------------------+
|    a.txt|a aa aaa aaaa aaaaa|
|    b.txt|b bb bbb bbbb bbbbb|
|    c.txt|c cc ccc cccc ccccc|
|    d.txt|d dd ddd dddd ddddd|
|    e.txt|e ee eee eeee eeeee|
+---------+-------------------+
```

This can happen with the snippet of code below

```
// create a scala spark context to use the wholeTextFiles method
val sc = spark.sparkContext

// create an RDD where the full path of each file is the key 
// and the file's content is the value,
// and get rid of the full path of the file
val input = sc.wholeTextFiles("hdfs://path/to/folder/*")
.map(file => (file._1.split('/').last, file._2))

// convert the RDD to a DataFrame and explicitly name the columns
val input_df = spark.createDataFrame(input).toDF("file_name", "content")
```

Comment: val rddFromFile = spark.sparkContext.wholeTextFiles("hdfs://master:9000/user/file/shakespeare")
    var listDoc = List[IndexDocument]()
    rddFromFile.collect().foreach(f=>{
      val indexDoc = IndexDocument(f._1, f._2)
      listDoc = listDoc :+ indexDoc
    })
    val rdd = sc.makeRDD(listDoc)
    EsSpark.saveToEs(rdd, "bigger")
I save this content to elasticsearch with 1Gb folder data, but it out of menory. How can I optimize code to put 1Gb data to ES? Or I must reduce my data ?

Comment: I put about 100Mb data is ok, but 1Gb cannot

Comment: What are the specs of the system/service you are running Spark on? This sounds more like a resources issue, because dataframes are the most optimised data types in Spark, and this may have to do with the RDD-based functions you are using to access the files.

Comment: I also have to mention that since this whole procedure is based on explicitly reading and manipulating input data in memory, you _will_ eventually reach to constraints in case your memory in insufficient, because it's a whole different case to have in-memory calculations for 100 small length text files versus 1.000.000 large length text files.

Comment: My spark cluster has 3 nodes, node master has 2.5gb ram and another node has 2GB RAM, node1 is running Elasticsearch, 3 node running hdfs

Comment: It seems like I suspected, RAM memory is too low for a small cluster to be able to in-parallel compute 1GB of data in memory. You either have to scale out the cluster by adding a few other nodes, or add more memory (because I don't thing that swap memory would do the trick, unfortunately). Either way, in case my answer is helpful and sufficient for your issue, please consider accepting it by clicking the "tick" :)

Comment: Thank you, Mr.Coursal. I tried your code in my application , I store RDD to DF and save DF to ES and it worked. Save RDD not work but save DF it works fine. It is true that DF is faster than RDD

Comment: Indeed, and I appreciate your kind words. Please consider "accepting" the answer above to show that your question has been answered for the people that are going to search for this in the future.